# Get (407) proxy authentication required on Win Application Development

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am a newbie C# programmer need use Facebook SDK to develop something. First, I write the sample code in asp.net. It was fine. But I move it to Win Application project on the same computer. It raised error "(407) proxy authentication required". Then I run it in my home, It have no problem.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = app_id,
                    client_secret = app_secret,
                    grant_type = "client_credentials"
                });
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

I have some question:

1. This have the proxy issue, why no error on the asp.net project?
2. How can I apply the proxy setting in the fb client?

Answer (score 2):

Even if its too late to answer, hope it may help someone. 
You can add the below in your Web Config.

```
 <system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
```

It will solve the above issue.